# How to run the same Javascript code on a single page, with different directions ( owl carousel)?

Tags: javascript, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm very new to Javascript so appreciate your help! I created this Owl slider (there are 2 sliders in this code), but want the second carousel to slide in the opposite direction. So the first carousel should slide left to right, and the second from right to left. However, when I add the direction:rtl to the code, it affects both carousels instead of just the bottom one. How can I amend the code so that both carousels slide in opposite directions?

You can view the codepen here --> https://codepen.io/ellie-oop/pen/KKmWLOQ  or the code is copied below (HTML, JS, CSS)

Thanks!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Flip Carousel</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="owl-carousel">
 <div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Phillip.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Phillip Richards</h3>
     <p>Managing Director and Financial Advisor</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Robert-Rich.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Robert Rich CFP®</h3>
     <p>Director and Financial Advisor</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Rohan-Gorringe.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Rohan Gorringe</h3>
     <p>Practice Principal</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Ray-Kan.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Ray Kan</h3>
     <p>Senior Financial Advisor & Head of Investments</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/MDP_Endorphin-9609-381x254-1.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Sanjeev Sharma</h3>
     <p>Senior Financial Advisor</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Michael-Sauer.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Michael Sauer CFP®</h3>
     <p>Financial Advisor</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Alexander-Rankin-Photo.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Alexander Rankin</h3>
     <p>Financial Advisor</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 
 <div class="owl-carousel">
 <div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Phillip.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Phillip Richards</h3>
     <p>Managing Director and Financial Advisor</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Robert-Rich.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Robert Rich CFP®</h3>
     <p>Director and Financial Advisor</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Rohan-Gorringe.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Rohan Gorringe</h3>
     <p>Practice Principal</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Ray-Kan.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Ray Kan</h3>
     <p>Senior Financial Advisor & Head of Investments</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/MDP_Endorphin-9609-381x254-1.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Sanjeev Sharma</h3>
     <p>Senior Financial Advisor</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Michael-Sauer.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Michael Sauer CFP®</h3>
     <p>Financial Advisor</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ewmcontainer">
<div class="ewmcontent">
 <a href="https://calendly.com/endorphinwealth" target="_blank">
   <div class="ewmcontent-overlay"></div>
   <img class="content-image" src="https://endorphinwealth.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Alexander-Rankin-Photo.jpg">
   <div class="content-details fadeIn-top">
     <h3>Alexander Rankin</h3>
     <p>Financial Advisor</p>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            center: true,
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            autoplay:true,
            autoplayTimeout:2000,
            autoplayHoverPause:false,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1,
                    nav:false
                },
                600:{
                    items:3,
                    nav:false
                },
                1000:{
                    items:3,
                    nav:false
                }
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  font-size: 16px;
}

.main-title{
  color: #2d2d2d;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 0.7em 0;
}

.ewmcontainer{
  padding: 1em 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
  .ewmcontainer{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px){
  .ewmcontainer{
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.ewmcontainer .title{
  color: #1a1a1a;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.ewmcontent {
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ewmcontent .ewmcontent-overlay {
  background: #0070bb;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.ewmcontent:hover .ewmcontent-overlay{
  opacity: 0.9!important;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content-image{
  width: 100%;
}

.content-details {
  position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.ewmcontent:hover .content-details{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.content-details h3{
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content-details p{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.fadeIn-top{
  top: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one `$(document).ready(function()` for each carousel, with a unique html element ID (`<div id="example-carousel">`) so each script call only one single carousel. You can also use unique class names (`<div class="example-carousel">`) Each carousel can now take in a different configuration object. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#carousel-top").owlCarousel({ 
        config: etc
        }
    })
})
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#carousel-bottom").owlCarousel({
        config: etc
        }
    })
})
```